# Get Rid of Windows Menu around Standalone Flash App?

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-2

I have a standalone Flash application that has its own File menu. You double-click the .swf file to launch it. How do I make the standard Windows window (the blue bar with the minimize, maximize, close buttons, as well as the "File, View, Control, Help" Bar) disappear so that my flash app is "naked?"

I'm using Flash Player 10 with ActionScript 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best way to solve this is to just run it as a fullscreen app.

```
fscommand("fullscreen",1); 
fscommand("allowscale","true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

http://www.northcode.com/forums/archive/index.php?t-1032.html

Comment: Hmm, that whole thread ends with the author emailing the guy offering help, with no solution...